# putExtra во ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Приветствую!

Я реализовал `RecyclerViewAdapter`, который получает данные из БД где порядка 100 пунктов, далее там же я реализовал метод `setOnClickListener`

```
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), HeadsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(HeadsActivity.mExtra, position);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Где по нажатию любой из пунктов происходит интент в главное активити с передачей данных по `id`, далее в главной активити я получаю данные и в соответствии с `id` я загружаю в пустой макет данные из БД,

```
    public static final String mExtra = "heads";

  .....

    final int heads = (Integer) getIntent().getExtras().get(mExtra);
```

Таким образом с каждым нажатием на пункт в `RecyclerView` используется один и тот же макет но заполняется он разными данными. Теперь я хочу перестроить приложение так, чтобы подобным образом у меня было во `ViewPager`, я хочу поместить список глав в выдвижное меню, и что бы по нажатию на любой пункт его `id` получал данные из БД, и чтобы использовался один макет, такое возможно? Также чтобы я мог прокручивать макет в право и влево и чтобы с прокруткой тоже в макет загружались данные в соответствии с `id` пункта.

Answer (score 0):

Да, так можно. Передавайте не один ID, но их список и во ViewPager отображайте фрагменты, в которые, в адаптере, при их создании, помещён ID через аргументы

Comment: Сказать честно, ничего не понял, но факт того что такое возможно уже радует.